# Skip columns in Excel when dragging COUNTIF formula to the right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula in F461

=COUNTIF(F137:F455,"Late")

When I copy it to G461 I want it to be (or the equivalent of)

=COUNTIF(H137:H455,"Late")

and so on, basically skipping 1 column each time.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use index to do it:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(137:455,0,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+6),"Late")
```

[image]